# 502 Proxy Error - PUT request to MDM OSX Server via apache ProxyPass on ubuntu 14

Tags: ssl, vhost

I am trying to set up a OSX Server behind an ubuntu server with apache2 and vhosts which uses proxypass to send requests to my OSX server. Most request work like they should but I am unable to make the put request work, I get the following error. This is result is via curl but it says the same thing.

> The proxy server could not handle the request PUT
>   /devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin

This is the command I used

> curl -k -X PUT
>   "https://mysupercoolserver.xyz/devicemanagement/api/device/mdm_checkin" -d
>   checkin-data.plist

The following is my vhost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysupercoolserver.xyz

        ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.40/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.40/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysupercoolserver.xyz

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests Off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLVerifyClient none
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mysupercoolserver_xyz.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mysupercoolserver_xyz.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/mysupercoolserver_xyz.ca-bundle
        ProxyPass / https://10.0.1.40/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.0.1.40/

        Timeout 2400
        ProxyTimeout 2400
        ProxyBadHeader Ignore

        ProxyPreserveHost on

        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1640>
        ServerName mysupercoolserver.xyz

        ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.40:1640/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.40:1640/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2195>
        ServerName mysupercoolserver.xyz

        ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.40:2195/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.40:2195/
        ProxyPreserveHost on        
        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Is there anything I can change here to solve the issue?** https:// works for downloading the profile and certificate and I know the other ports work as well since requests are going through.